# Highcharts sankey draggable nodes

Tags: highcharts, draggable, sankey-diagram

I have been trying to create a HighCharts sankey diagram with draggable nodes.

This should be possible from the documentation, but I am not able to get it working.

Is this possible in the first place and how can I achieve this? Can someone share a 'fiddle' ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use the `draggable-points` module with a sankey series. As you can see there is no `dragDrop` property in sankey API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey, like for example in column series: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dragDrop

You can suggest a new feature request here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose